# How to access the specific locations of an integer list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an integer list which should be used as indices of another list to retrieve a value. Lets say we have following array

```
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

We can get the specific elements using following code

```
    import operator
    operator.itemgetter(1,2,3)(a)
```

It will return the 2nd, 3rd and 4th item.

Lets say i have another list

```
    b=[1,2,3]
```

But if I try to run the following code it gets an error

```
    operator.itemgetter(b)(a)
```

I am wondering if someone could help me please. I think its just the problem that I have to convert the b to comma seprated indices butnot very sure.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use *:

```
operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)
```

The * in a function call means, unpack this value, and use its elements as the arguments to the function.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged your question with the numpy tag, you could also consider making a an array so this works:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b = [1,2,3]
a[b]
```

Comment: While array(operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)) is perhaps less legible, it is faster than array(a)[b] if you need the output to be an array. So still go with Ned's solution if the output should be an array and you don't care about legibility.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to itemgetter needs to be a tuple.  You can do this with:

```
apply(operator.itemgetter, tuple(b))(a)
```

There might be a cleaner/more idomatic way of doing this, but this does work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
map(a.__getitem__, b)
```

The code returns a list in Python 2 or an iterator in Python 3. If you need to convert it to tuple, just put it in a `tuple()`.